# Can I use regex to split pandas dataframe column on first match only?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

A column in my dataframe has the following campaign contribution data formatted in one of two ways:

```
JOHN A. DONOR1234 W ROAD ST CITY, STATE 56789
```

And

```
JANE M. DONOR
1234 W ROAD ST
CITY, STATE 56789
```

I want to split this column into two. Column one should be the name of the donor. Column two should be the address.

Currently, I'm using the following `regex` code to try and accomplish this:

```
url = ("http://www.voterfocus.com/CampaignFinance/candidate_pr.php?op=rp&e=8&c=munmiamibeach&ca=64&sdc=116&rellevel=4&dhc=774&committee=N")
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]
df['Contributor'].str.split(r'\d\d?', expand=True)
```

But instead of splitting after the first match and quitting - as I intend - the regex seems continue matching and splitting. My output should looke like this:

```
Col1                    Col2
JOHN A. DONOR          1234 W ROAD ST CITY, STATE 56789
```

Comment: Please include _all_ examples of what the data looks like.  Don't leave us guessing.

Answer (score 0):

it may be much simpler than that.  You can use the string methods.  For example, I think this is the behavior you want:

```
import pandas as pd
s = """JOHN A. DONOR
1234 W ROAD ST
CITY, STATE 56789"""

df = pd.DataFrame([s], columns=["donors"])
df.donors.str.split("\n", 1, expand=True)
```

output:

```
               0                                  1
0  JOHN A. DONOR  1234 W ROAD ST\nCITY, STATE 56789
```

Comment: It's clear I asked my question wrong. There isn't always a new line break between the name and address - that's why I attempted regex based on the beginning address numbers since it was the only way I could separate the data that seemed applicable in every instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Splitting solution**

You can use

```py
df['Contributor'].str.split(r'(?<=\D)(?=\d)', expand=True, n=1)
```

The `(?<=\D)(?=\d)` regex finds a location between a non-digit char (`\D`) and a digit char (`\d`), splits the string there and only performs this operation once (due to `n=1`).

**Alternative solution**

You can match and capture the names up to the first number, and then capture all text there remains after and including the first digit using

```py
df['Contributor'].str.extract(r'(?P<Name>\D*)(?P<Address>\d.*)', expand=True)
# =>                                            Name                                         #   Address
#   0                  Contributor  CHRISTIAN ULVERT                1742 W FLAGLER STMIAMI, FL 33135
#   1                     Contributor  Roger Thomson               4271 Alton Miami Beach , FL 33140
#   2                Contributor  Steven Silverstein          691 West 247th Street Bronx , NY 10471
#   3                      Contributor  Cathy Raduns           691 West 247th Street Bronx, NY 10471
#   4          Contributor  Asher Raduns-Silverstein            691 West 247th StreetBRONX, NY 10471
```

The `(?P<Name>\D*)(?P<Address>\d.*)` pattern means

- `(?P<Name>\D*)` - Group "Name": zero or more chars other than digits
- `(?P<Address>\d.*)` - Group "Address": a digit and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars.

If there are line breaks in the string, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern, i.e. `r'(?s)(?P<Name>\D*)(?P<Address>\d.*)'`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WFvwNc/1).